# Find one or the other or both values in range, different result for each

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to automatically update a text based on the values found in a range (Sheet=information 36:36). If the range only contains "red" then the result should be "red text", if the range only contains blue, the result should be "blue text". However if both values are found the result should be "purple text"

I can make it get one or the other but I cannot get the desired result when both values are found.
I tried some variations of COUNTIF and SUMPRODUCT but the formula below best shows what I want ( even though this formula doesn't work)

```
=IF(COUNTIF([Information!36:36,="blue", "blue text",IF(COUNTIF(Information!36:36,="red","red text",IF(COUNTIF(Information!36:36, ="red",Information!36:36,="blue", "purple text"))
```

This shows what I want to get. If there is at least one "red"  the result =red, at least one blue=blue, at least one of both=purple

[image]

Could someone perhaps help me with the formula?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this works:

```
=IF(AND(COUNTIF(2:2,"red")>=1,COUNTIF(2:2,"blue")>=1),"Purple",IF(COUNTIF(2:2,"red")>=1,"Red",IF(COUNTIF(2:2,"blue")>=1,"Blue")))

Note, I have not changed the image though.
```

The testing logic and values are important.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. However the range is all of row 36, the number of entries is variable so I cannot use (A2:C2, red)>3. I will make a picture and update my question

Comment: But you could update the answer I gave you to deal with your data. I have shown how to deal with finding both "red" and "blue" using and()....

Comment: @user17269242 check out the edit...

Comment: If I change the code to work over the range when the minimum for the result is 1 it just takes the first result in de formula if both values are found instead of the mixed result. `=IF(COUNTIF(Information!36:36,"red")>0,"red",IF(COUNTIF(Information!36:36,"blue")>0,"blue",IF(AND(COUNTIF(Information!36:36,"red")>0,COUNTIF(Information!36:36,"blue"))>0,"Purple")))`

Comment: Works on mine, but you changed things, so you need to work out the consequences of what you changed... The way you test now, you won't get to purple...

Comment: Exactly, I just get either blue or red.

Did you try my last version of your formula (with range 4:4)?
Cause the only thing I changed (other than the range) is that the minimum is >0.

Comment: I just looked at it and that is why I told you that you will never get purple with your version. Once you have red or blue it is game over - you never get to the third test. Think about why I tested as I did. As I said you need to evaluate the consequences of what you changed.

Comment: Yes, that brings me to my original question.. I don't know how to get purple haha

Comment: @user17269242 so check out my final edit.

Comment: Great, thank you very much ;)